# Matching a range

Tags: excel, vba, match

I would like to know is there a method to match a range? For example I have data in 
A1:F1 and I want to find and match this values or this range (exactly same values in same order) in another sheet or in a different range (example: H15:M15).

How do I do this? I know how to find and match a single value.

Comment: You can't perform an equivalency test (i.e., `Debug.Print (Range("A1:A5").Value = Range("C1:C5").Value)` on a range or a variant array. You'll have to use some combination of `Find` (to find the first cell's value` and then an iteration to check subsequent cells.  If all cells match, then the range matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function RowsMatch(rng1, rng2)
    RowsMatch = join(application.transpose(application.transpose(rng1)),chr(0))= _
                join(application.transpose(application.transpose(rng2)),chr(0))

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

in an excel formula, you could use something like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:F1=H15:M15))
```

and check to see if it equals the number of cells.
in VBA, as `WorksheetFunction.SumProduct` is a difficult one to program, you can use

```
evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:F1=H15:M15))")
```

and, again, check to see if the result is the number of cells being compared

Comment: "WorksheetFunction.SumProduct is a difficult one to program" How so??

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, while it's easy to put in ranges and multiply, the type of tricks used here (the double negative) are not readily accepted, or not easy to incorporate into the ranges that the vba requires